# How to be able to access from a callback the surrounding class and the object instance the method accepting the callback as parameter belongs to?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-sqlite3

Probably the title's terrify worded. I'm only using sqlite3 as a db in a nodejs environment, its api operations are callback-based and passed callbacks are bound to an sqlite3.RunResult object from which you can access the actual operation metrics. But, there are also states belonging to the lexically surrounding class I defined that I need to have access to in order to emit custom events to an event bus (shared across multiple custom classes). *This is not the complete class definition*.

**The db.run method** is one of those I want to access from their callback both, the surrounding class instance and the sqlite3.RunResults object. What is a good approach to achieve this?

```
import { EventEmitter } from "node:events"
import sqlite3, { Database, RunResult } from "sqlite3";

class PostDB {

    public constructor(
        private eventEmitter: EventEmitter,
        private dbPath: string = Path.join(process.cwd(), "db", "instagramPosts.db"),
        callback: (() => void) | null = null,
    ) {

        this.open(callback)
    }

    public addPosts(posts: Post[]) {
        //TODO FIX

        return new Promise((allResolve, allReject) => {
            this.db?.all(
                `SELECT username, postTitle FROM Posts`, (err: Error, rows: any) => {
                    const forPromises: Promise<unknown>[] = []

                    posts.forEach((post) => {

                        let row = rows.find((row: any) =>
                            row.username === post.meta.options.username && row.postTitle === post.meta.postTitle
                        )

                        if (!row) {

                            let serialize: Promise<unknown> =  new Promise((resolveSerialize, rejectSerialize) => {
                                this.db?.serialize(async () => {

                                    await Promise.all([
                                        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                                            this.db?.run(`
                                                INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Users (username, password)
                                                SELECT $username, $password
                                                WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE username = $username)
                                        `, {
                                                $username: post.meta.options.username,
                                                $password: post.meta.options.password

                                            }, (err: Error) => {

                                                if (err)
                                                    throw err

                                                if ((this as unknown as sqlite3.RunResult).lastID)
                                                    this.eventEmitter.emit(this.NEW_POST_EVENT)

                                                else logger.info(`Post with title "${post.meta.postTitle}" and user "${post.meta.options.username}" already exists. Skipping.`)

                                                logger.info(`INSERTED USER "${post.meta.options.username}" with password "${post.meta.options.password}"`)

                                                resolve(true)

                                            })
                                        }),

                                        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                                            this.db?.run(`
                                        INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Posts(postTitle, username, caption, discoveredAt, published) 
                                        SELECT $postTitle, $username, $caption, $discoveredAt, $published
                                        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Posts WHERE postTitle = $postTitle and username = $username)
                                    `,
                                                {
                                                    $postTitle: post.meta.postTitle,
                                                    $username: post.meta.options.username,
                                                    $caption: post.caption,
                                                    $discoveredAt: post.meta.discoveredAt,
                                                    $published: post.meta.published

                                                },
                                                (err: Error) => {
                                                    if (err) {
                                                        throw err
                                                    }
                                                    logger.info(`The post "${post.meta.postTitle}" with username "${post.meta.options.username}" has been inserted into Post table"`);
                                                    resolve(true)
                                                });
                                        }),

                                        new Promise((resolveInnerSerialize, rejectInnerSerialize) => {
                                            const serializePromises: Promise<unknown>[] = []

                                            this.db?.serialize(() => {
                                                post.instagramFiles.forEach(file => {

                                                    let insertPostFilesPromise = new Promise((resolveInnerRun, rejectInnerRun) => {

                                                        this.db?.run(`INSERT INTO InstagramFiles(username, postTitle, filePath) VALUES(?, ?, ?)`,
                                                            [post.meta.options.username, post.meta.postTitle, file],
                                                            (err) => {
                                                                if (err) {

                                                                    if (err.message.includes("SQLITE_CONSTRAINT"))
                                                                        logger.error(err.message);
                                                                    else throw err

                                                                }

                                                                logger.info(`InstagramFile "${file}" of post "${post.meta.postTitle}" and user "${post.meta.options.username}" inserted with id ""`);

                                                                resolveInnerRun(true)

                                                            });

                                                    })

                                                    serializePromises.push(insertPostFilesPromise)
                                                });

                                                Promise.all(serializePromises)
                                                .then(() => {
                                                    resolveInnerSerialize(true)
                                                })
                                            })
                                        }),

                                        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                                            this.db?.run(`INSERT INTO Options(username, postTitle, doPublish) VALUES(?, ?, ?)`,
                                                [post.meta.options.username, post.meta.postTitle, Number(post.meta.options.doPublish)],
                                                (err) => {
                                                    if (err) {
                                                        logger.error(err.message);
                                                        throw err
                                                    }

                                                    logger.info(`Option "doPublish" of post "${post.meta.postTitle}" AND user "${post.meta.options.username}" with row id "" has been inserted into Options table`);

                                                    resolve(true)
                                                });

                                        })
                                    ])

                                })

                                resolveSerialize(true)
                            })

                            forPromises.push(serialize)
                        }

                    });

                    Promise.all(forPromises)
                    .then(() => { allResolve(true) })

                })

        })


    }
}
```

I tried:

1. Unwrapping all functionality from a class and isolating it in a module so that I can access it from closure context rather than the "this" pointer, this way I don't have a to share a "this" pointer among multiple contexts.
2. Define callback, assign it to variable and then create new enumerable property with the reference of my class instance dynamically.

Comment: wow, callback  hell. I would look at [better-sqlite3](https://github.com/WiseLibs/better-sqlite3) which is fully synchronous with the note that *'node-sqlite3 uses asynchronous APIs for tasks that are either CPU-bound or serialized. That's not only bad design, but it wastes tons of resources. It also causes mutex thrashing which has devastating effects on performance.'*